# History in the Almquist shell in the NetBSD

Tags: shell, command-history, netbsd, ash

In NetBSD `/bin/sh` is a modified version of the [Almquist shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell). With the command `fc -l` it is possible to view the last 16 commands typed in the prompt in the **current** session and **not the older ones**.

The environment variable `HISTSIZE` is set at 1000 and in `bash` this means that the last 1000 commands (**whether or not** they were typed in the current session) are saved in a file named `.bash_history` in the home directory. But here it seems to mean just that the last 1000 commands in this session are keeped in the history, and the history does not seem to be saved in a file.

I am looking for a history which allows not only to read the last commands of the current session, but also **the commands of the previous sessions** (for example, the previous time I started the system, not the actual time). Does `/bin/sh` in NetBSD have by default **such an history**? If not, is it possible to create such an history in that shell?

Comment: So you need the file where ash(1) saves its history?

Comment: Yes, the NetBSD version of ash, if such a file exists!

Comment: It seems to be using libedit - so it might be for example `~/.history`. In any case you can try to find out the file name by spawning a shell, issuing a couple of benign commands, exiting and looking for recently modified files. If history will have been written, you'll see it with something like `find ~ -cmin -5`.

Comment: I tried to do this, but the `find` command does not identify any modified file. I tried also to put `HISTFILE=~/.history`, but after some commands the file had not even been created.

Comment: `lsof` might help :)

Comment: `lsof` is not installed by default. I had problems with the packages (package not found!) but I will retry.

Comment: NetBSD offers `/bin/ksh` which is an enhanced shell which is otherwise more or less backward compatible with `/bin/sh`, and you'll find some clues in the fine manual for `ksh(1)` about how it supports storing and reloading command history to/from a file.

Answer (score 5):

I don't really understand your question, what's the actual question?

First you are stating that you can access the history via the `fc` builtin and then you are asking if the shell implements a history?

Furthermore, the [`man page` states](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi/man?sh++NetBSD-6.0):

> The number of previous commands that can be accessed are determined by the value of the `HISTSIZE` variable.

and

> A login shell first
>        reads commands from the files `/etc/profile` and `.profile` if they exist.
>        If the environment variable `ENV` is set on entry to a shell, or is set in
>        the `.profile` of a login shell, the shell next reads commands from the
>        file named in `ENV`.  Therefore, a user should place commands that are to
>        be executed only at login time in the `.profile` file, and commands that
>        are executed for every shell inside the `ENV` file.  To set the `ENV` vari-
>        able to some file, place the following line in your `.profile` of your home
>        directory
>
> ```
>       ENV=$HOME/.shinit; export ENV
> ```
>
> substituting for `.shinit` any filename you wish.

If your question is whether history gets written to a file, it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: I modified my question to make it more clear. I was exactly asking if history gets written to a file and if it is possible to make history written to a file in this type of shell in NetBSD.

Comment: @BowPark It does not look like it, but since `PS1` is subject to parameter expansion you could probably hack around this by doing e.g. `PS1='$(fc -ln -1 2>/dev/null >>~/.history)'${your_actual_prompt}`. But you should check the `sh` and `libedit` source code first if there really is no "native" way of writing to a file, despite the documentation not mentioning anything like it.