# FreeBSD sh: is it possible to import a list of commands into fc without executing them?

Tags: shell, freebsd, fc

I cannot find any indication that sh supports persistent history. So I am trying to create this functionality manually. At the end of my .shrc history I have added this:

```
trap -- 'fc -ln -- 1 >> "$HOME/.sh_history"' EXIT
```

This ensures that every time I exit the shell that the commands I have entered in that session are not lost in wind.

Now that I have the saving history bit sorted out, I am wanting to import all commands in `~/.sh_history` into fc upon logging in so that I can call commands from previous shell sessions.

I realize that it won't be quite as simple as this because I will have to find a way to make sure that I only append new commands to the end of `~.sh_history`, but I am confident I can hack it out provided that it is even possible to give a list of commands to fc without executing them.

Comment: Background: `sh` on FreeBSD is `ash`, a modified Almquist Shell. It has no `HISTFILE`.

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137399/ .

Comment: FreeBSD `sh` is a fork of `ash`, yes, but now it is being developed independently from the original upstream. Also, it does support `HISTFILE` now.